# Determinant of a symmetric matrix with entries on diagonals

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, symmetric-matrices

I am interested in the calculation of the determinant of the $N\times N$ symmetric matrix
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf B = \left(\begin{array}{*{20}c}
2 & & -1& &-1& &\\
 & 2 & & -1&  & \ddots&    \\
 -1& & \ddots&  &\ddots & & -1 \\
 & -1& & & &-1&  \\
 -1& & \ddots&  &2 &&-1 \\
 &\ddots & &-1  & &2& \\
  & &-1 &  &-1 & &2   \\
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}
where the first $-1$ on the left in the first line from left to right is at position n, and the second $-1$ at position $m>n$. The blank parts of the matrix are implicitly filled with zeros.

Are there results or properties for such class of matrices that would allow to compute the determinant for any dimension $N$, without its explicit calculation (that could be accomplished e.g. via Leibniz formula for determinants)?

Comment: Have I understood correctly that the matrix is all zeros except for five diagonals; the main diagonal with all twos, and two pairs of diagonals of $-1$s symmetric about the main diagonal? Because at first glance (before reading) I assumed it was a checkerboard pattern.

Comment: It is correct as you mention in the first place i.e. there are five diagonals; two pairs of them are symmetric w.r.t. the main one.